# Using Mysql or PowerBI and 3 tables(datasets), how do you add working days to date sold?

Tags: mysql, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have the following tables in Mysql server and PowerBI (a solution for any of them works).

**Sales Table**

```
Date sold | Product | item | address
24-11-2018 | socks | 02 | orlando 
26-11-2018 | socks | 02 | mexico df
```

**Calendar table**

```
Date | isWeekend | isHoliday | isWorkday
24-11-2018 | 1 |  0 | 0
25-11-2018 | 1 |  1 | 0
26-11-2018 | 0 |  0 | 1
27-11-2018 | 0 |  0 | 1
```

**Days to Deliver By Location table**

```
address | days to deliver in workdays
orlando |  4
```

I need to add a new column in "Sales Table" where i get the "Date to Deliver", which is the sum of "Date Sold" + Days to deliver". Now, the problem i have is that i can't / don't know how i can manage to add only the working days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would filter the `Calendar` table, add a running/cumulative workday column, and then match that the `days to deliver` value to the correct cumulative row.

```
Date to Deliver =
VAR Dates = FILTER ( 'Calendar', 'Calendar'[Date] > Sales[Date sold] )
VAR CumDays =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        Dates,
        "CumWorkdays", CALCULATE (
            SUM ( 'Calendar'[isWorkday] ),
            FILTER ( Dates, 'Calendar'[Date] <= EARLIER ( [Date] ) )
        )
    )
VAR DaysToDeliver =
    LOOKUPVALUE (
        DaysToDeliverByLocation[days to deliver in workdays],
        DaysToDeliverByLocation[address], Sales[address]
    )
RETURN
    MINX ( FILTER ( CumDays, [CumWorkdays] = DaysToDeliver ), [Date] )
```

Comment: This is a PowerBI solution. Gonna test and let you know. Thanks

Comment: The solution for PowerBI worked!!.. except for one thing, the return was giving me the Date even if it wasn't a workday. Please, if you know why let me know. <br/> 

Meaneanwhile, i found a workaround by addying  "isworday=1" to the return filter<br/> 

RETURN
    MAXX ( FILTER ( CumDays, [CumWorkdays] = DaysToDeliver & [IsWorkday] = 1 ), [Date] )

Comment: Oh, good call. The cumulative work days would be the same for a Friday and the following Saturday and Sunday. A simpler adjustment would be to switch to `MINX` instead of `MAXX`.

Comment: thanks for answering so fast. So by applying Minx i wouldn't need to add isworday = 1, right? Gonna try and i let you know.

By the way if anyone else has a solution using MYSQL, help is welcome :)

Comment: I believe that would eliminate the need for the extra condition, but give it a test to be sure.